# Unwanted gray line using mdframed

Tags: mdframed, framed, amsthm, thmtools

I'm using mdframed to surround my theorem environment with a double line on the left side (trying to reproduce Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology"). It works nearly perfectly, except for two little horizontal gray lines joining my main vertical lines:

[image]

Here is a minimal code which produced the above picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\mdfdefinestyle{double-line}{%
outerlinewidth=0.4pt,%
innerlinewidth=0.4pt,%
middlelinewidth=1.5pt,%
middlelinecolor=white,%
innertopmargin=-6.5pt,%
innerbottommargin=1pt,% 
innerleftmargin = 5pt,%
bottomline=false,%
topline=false,%
rightline=false}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=double-line]{thm}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\lipsum[3]
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Does anybody have any idea why these gray lines appear, and how to remove them?

---

EDIT: Thanks to @Sigur's comment, I found Hatcher's solution on his website (http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/typography.html, point 4) :

```
\long\def\proclaim #1. #2\par{\bigbreak\vbox{\hbox {\vrule\kern1.5pt\vrule
\everypar{\leftskip 5pt\rightskip 4pt}\vbox{\noindent {\bf #1.\enspace}{\sl#2}}}}
\par\ifdim\lastskip<\medskipamount \removelastskip\penalty55\medskip\fi}
```

However, I'm not sure how to use this code such that it surrounds my theorem environment. Any idea ?

---

EDIT2/3: @Bernard's solution is almost perfect, but I noticed that it behaves badly with lists when not using parskip, and it behaves badly with short ending line when using parskip.

### With `parskip`

Spacing between between `theorem` environment and `proof` environment are too big, but it seems unrelated to the double bar environment, so I created another question (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522809/additional-space-around-proof-using-parskip/522814#522814)).

Nonetheless, when a theorem environment finishes with a short line, the double bar is not long enough:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newenvironment{dbleftbar}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{\vrule width0.6pt\hspace{0.15em}\vrule width0.6pt \hspace{0.5em}}%
  \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}

% With parskip
\usepackage{parskip}
\declaretheorem[%
name            =Theorem,%
postheadhook    =\vspace*{\parskip}\begin{dbleftbar}\vspace*{-5pt},%
prefoothook     =\vspace*{-1pt}\end{dbleftbar}%
]{Thm}

\begin{document}
\begin{Thm}\leavevmode
\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]
    \item Lorem i
\end{enumerate}
\end{Thm}
\hrule

\begin{Thm}\leavevmode
\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]
    \item Lorem ip
\end{enumerate}
\end{Thm}
\hrule

\begin{Thm}
Lorem
\end{Thm}
\hrule

\begin{Thm}
Lorem ip
\end{Thm}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

### Without `parskip`

Here, the double bar is much longer when using list.

[image]

Comment: If I am not wrong, you can find the macros used by Hatcher in its personal webpage.

Comment: @Sigur: the `nosep` option from `enumitem` is enough.

Comment: @Bernard, thanks for letting me know. I didn't know that option.

Comment: For the short line, adding `\strut` at the end should fix the problem.  Yes, it's a manual adjustment, but worth the effort, per Knuth's philosophy.

Comment: Yep, I guess if no better solution arises I can always adjust space manually. That is quite unsatisfying though (also because this is quite a weird bug that would be worth solving once and for all)

Answer (score 3):

I propose a solution with the `framed` package and `thmtools`.
`Framed` defines a`leftbar` environment, that I modified to obtain a doublebar  via a `leftdblbar`  environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}

\newenvironment{dbleftbar}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{\vrule width0.6pt\hspace{0.15em}\vrule width0.6pt \hspace{0.5em}}%
  \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, postheadhook=\begin{dbleftbar}\rule{0pt}{2ex}, prefoothook=\smallskip\end{dbleftbar}]{Thm}

\begin{document}

\begin{Thm}
\lipsum[11]
\end{Thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot ! that's excatly what I needed. (If anybody has an explanation for these gray lines, I'm still interested.)

Comment: I noticed that the spacing is much bigger when using lists. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Do you mean the theorem contents ends with a list?

Comment: yes. I added an edit to my original answer

Comment: For the spacing after a list,  load `enumitem` and use `\begin{enumerate}nosep]`. I would add , for aesthetic reasons,  `[wide=0pt, margin*, font=\upshape]`. For `parskip`, I don't see any peoblem loading this package. Could you post a small code showing the problem?

Comment: After some investigations, I edited my original question with more details

Comment: I'm not sure: what is the problem with using the `wide` option?

Comment: If you mean technical problem, none, at least with `parskip`; if you mean esthetic problem, well I would prefer to be able to use the "normal" list as well (e.g., the wide option is a bit weird for very short lists).

Comment: To have a wide *and* normal list, you can use the  options `wide=0pt, leftmargin=*`, so the list label will not be indented, but the contents of each item will be.

Comment: Okay after more testing, it seems that actually there is a problem with `wide`, just as for other options (my testing examples were simply unfortunate). The problem comes when the last line is to short (the threshold seems to be 8 characters). I will edit my question.

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem to be specific to list