# Grey line connecting outside line with contents of mdframed

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

This is the same problem as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522687/unwanted-gray-line-using-mdframed), however none of the solutions really helped.

In short: when drawing the following box using `mdframed`, a thin grey line is shown to connect the main box with the left line, which I do not want.
[image: erronous linedrawing by mdframed]

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}


\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[topline=false,bottomline=false,
     leftline=true,rightline=false,
     backgroundcolor=black!10,
     middlelinewidth=6pt,middlelinecolor=white,
     outerlinewidth=0.5pt]
    \lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Using `pstricks` also does not change this, and the default drawing style does not appear to allow for coloring the middle line, which creates the seperation.
Furthermore, the presence of the line does seem to depend on which pdfviewer one uses. Acrobat does not display it, but most others do. It also does not matter whether I use pdflatex, xelatex or lualatex.

I'm open to using a different package to draw the frame, but for instance `framed` does not allow for much customization as far as I'm aware, and the solution offered in the question linked above does not seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried `tcolorbox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the thin grey line except in SumatraPDF, but if you want to give a chance to `tcolorbox` (it doesn't show the line in SumatraPDF), here you have the code to mimic your `mdframed` box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[topline=false,bottomline=false,
     leftline=true,rightline=false,
     backgroundcolor=black!10,
     middlelinewidth=6pt,middlelinecolor=white,
     outerlinewidth=0.5pt]
    \lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, sharp corners, colback=black!10, boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,  top = 5pt, bottom =5pt, left = 10pt, right=10pt, borderline west={0.5pt}{-6.5pt}{black}, left skip = 6.5pt, boxsep=0pt ]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Following picture show the result I see in TeXworks viewer (windows)

[image]

and following one a zoomed detail in SumatraPDF. As you can see `tcolorbox` (bottom box) doesn't show the grey line

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much! Shame that this just seems to be a bug of `mdframed`, but great that another solution is available.